# IF Statement Query Syntax Error

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to replace a `foreach` statement with a single SQL query, my code I want to change looks like this:

```
 this.Settings = new List<Setting>()
        {
            // Write all the settings from the VB
            new Setting() { Name = "NOOFORDERS", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "ORDNVGREQ", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "IncWendsDel", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "AUTOEMAIL_INVOICE", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "REQEMAIL_INVOICE", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "REQEMAIL_SALES", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "REQEMAIL_PICKSLIP", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "REQEMAIL_DESPATCH", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "CARRPARTSHIP", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "DELNOTEREQ", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "REQ_CARRPARTSHIP", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "BUDGETREQ", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "PriceList", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "EmployeeRenew", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "Warehouse", Value = null },
            new Setting() { Name = "EmployeeDetails", Value = null },
        };
var value = this.db.tblbus_setvalues.Where( x => x.SettingID == setting.Name && x.BusinessCode == this.Business.BusinessCode ).FirstOrDefault().Value;
switch (value.GetType())
{
    case typeof(bool):
        (value) ? setting.Value = "true" : setting.Value = "false";
        break;
    default:
        setting.Value = value.ToString();
        break;
    }
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting.Value) ) setting.Value = this.db.tblbus_settings.Where( x => x.SettingID == setting.Name ).FirstOrDefault().Default.ToString();
```

My SQL which I want to replace the above code with looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.SettingID, t2.Value, t1.Default
FROM `tblbus_settings` t1
LEFT JOIN `tblbus_setvalues` t2
ON t1.SettingID = t2.SettingID
WHERE `BusinessCode` = "XXX" // Dependency
AND t1.`BusType` = "CUS"
```

Can anyone help me write an IF statement onto this SQL query which will only display the `t2.Value` if the `t1.Default` is **null**?

I tried things like:

```
IF(t2.value == NULL) { t1.Default }
ELSE { t2.Value }
```

But they all give me SQL syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values:

```
 SELECT t1.SettingID, COALESCE(t2.Value, t1.Default) FROM ...
```

Comment: This returned 141 rows where there should be 150 rows :/ Strange - investigation time but thanks for the source! I'll mark it when I can

Comment: This is a better answer than the one I submitted, go with this :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT t1.SettingID, t2.Value, t1.Default, 
CASE t1.Default IS NOT NULL
   THEN t1.Default 
   ELSE t2.Value
FROM `tblbus_settings` t1
LEFT JOIN `tblbus_setvalues` t2
ON t1.SettingID = t2.SettingID
WHERE `BusinessCode` = "XXX" // Dependency
AND t1.`BusType` = "CUS"
```

See this for meore https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx